# PHP Get 1st weekday

Tags: php, math, date

I have tried to find the 1st weekday from a specified date, but I have not figured out any solution, but I am thinking, that you can do something like strtotime("-x days", $time)

Just now I am using this method to calculate how many days to go back, but I want to know, if this can be optimized in any way

```
if ($i == 0)
   return 6;
else
   return $i-1;
```

Where $i is the numeric representation of the day of the week (same as PHP's date('w'))

I also need to find the last day of a week, but there I think, you can do

```
strtotime('+'.date('w', $dateTo).'days', $dateTo);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "1st weekday" ?

Comment: For clarification, is this a valid use case?  You enter Feb 20th (a Sunday), and it returns the 21st (a Monday).  If you enter Feb 16th (a Wednsday), it returns Feb 16th.

Comment: $jnpcl The 1st monday of a week.

Comment: @Jonah If you enter Feb 20th it should return Feb 14th. If you enter Feb 16th, it should return Feb 14th too

Comment: @The87Boy: but that breaks consistency.  You're going back a week on the first one.

Comment: @Jonah Not in Denmark. Here the week starts on a monday ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's all relative date math. If you've got a proper PHP timestamp, then it's just a simple integer. `date('w')` is the proper method for extracting a day-of-week value from that timestamp, but the rest can be done with regular math:

```
$today = date('w', $dateTo);
$last_sunday = $dateTo - (86400 * $today); // same time on previous sunday
$last_day_of_week = $dateTo + (86400 * (6 % $today));
```

This is faster than `round-tripping` everything through `strtotime()` and incurring the date string parsing penalties.

Comment: If it is faster, than round-tripping throug `strtotime()`, then I still need to do the math as refered to earlier, because a week starts on a monday in Denmark

Comment: well, 'w' returns a 0/sunday-based week. 'N' returns 1/monday-based.

Comment: Oh, I have not seen 'N', when I looked in the list :o But as I can see, I only can use 'Z', as my host is only using PHP 5.0

Answer (score 2):

Try using `strtotime()` with a [relative format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php). Something like this should work:
`strtotime('monday', $relativeTime);` for the first weekday and `strtotime('friday', $relativeTime);` for the last weekday.